# Is it possible to detect a biased die using methods similar to the Elitzur-Vaidman bombs? Essentially without rolling the dice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

Once you roll a biased dice $x$ number of times, it becomes clear wheter or not it is biased. This is because one number will come up more times than the usual chance i.e. 1/6. You can improve your results by increasing the number of trials.

But is there a way to determine the bias without having to roll the dice? Can we use an idea similar to the one used in [elitzur vaidman bombs](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/resources/elitzur-vaidman-bombs/) , where quantum mechanics is applied to determine whether or not a bomb is active without detonating it?

In our case, how would we define bias? Is it simple a mass defect on a square dice? Does the shape of the dice induce some bias?

Comment: You can measure the weight distribution in dice. Theoretically one can even do it without moving them by measuring their gravity. These are perfectly classical measurements that have nothing to do with quantum mechanics.

Comment: X-ray or MRI might do it.

Comment: Once we know that dice can be altered (say shave a corner or 2, without altering CG/CM) ..... then we could investigate how the di was produced .... if we knew it came from the same place where other biased dice were produced ... then yes we DO NOT need to roll it to know.

Comment: Or if we actually saw the di being altered (by chipping a corner etc) then yes we DO NOT need to roll it to know.

Comment: They test die using a float test but there are limitations:  Dice Testing with the Running Chi-Square Distribution https://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1006&context=seas_faculty_pubs

Comment: +1 I disagree with the closing of this question

Answer (score 2):

With biased dice, you would need have more mass close to one side (face), away from the geometric center of the cube, unlike you would find in a fair dice with the center of mass coinciding with the (roughly) geometric center.

Say it is heavier close to the face "6". This means that most of the time you roll it, you would find it gives you the opposite face of the "6" (not having a die here, I'm not sure what face that would be, so say "1").

If you wanted to determine this without rolling the dice, what you could do is grab a glass of water and fill it with enough salt so that when you put the die in the water, it should float at the top with a face up about level with the surface, and the rest submerged.
Now place the die in the saltwater solution, spin it around and when it stops rotating, if the face "6" points to the bottom of the glass as it floats, you know it's heavier close to the same face, meaning this die is biased$^1$. So that when you roll it on a smooth surface, most of the time you will get the result "1" (the opposite face).

Of course if you find that another face points bottom down in the glass, the number on the opposite face will be favored during rolling on a smooth surface.

The reason this occurs is because gravity will pull down with a stronger force on the heavier side, causing this side to be pulled face down so as to minimize potential energy.

$^1$ Obviously there is no such thing as a die with a perfect mass distribution, so you should take note of things like how quickly the die orients itself with that face down, do the test a few times, and run comparisons with other die of the same kind.

Comment: Its much simpler than that ..... maybe we know the di is altered from its history or we have seen it being altered.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Sure, though OP is asking how can we experimentally deduce the die is biased without rolling it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answers here should not be referring to classical mass distribution measurements. Of course those are possible. The question is about whether it's also possible to adapt the [Elitzur Vaidman bomb tester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester) to this case.

I would say yes because you can enter a superposition of having rolled the die many times and having not rolled it at all. Just replace the bomb with a device which performs the dice rolls when it receives a photon and lets that photon through if and only if it finds bias (the dud case).

Comment: How many times would you have to 'roll' the dice in this manner to find if it is biased or not ? Is this still the same as never rolling the dice ?

Comment: That of course depends on how biased it is. A die that's supposed to make someone money at a casino could probably be found out in 100 rolls. Whether it's the same as never rolling the dice is a philosophical question. But as with the bomb, there is a probability that the experiment would output an answer while looking to us like it has not rolled.